# In the Coronam series, why is flying planet-to-planet safer than flying above or below the plane of the ecliptic?

Tags: coronam

In the *[Coronam](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/w/johnny-worthen/coronam/)* series by Johnny Worthen, he describes space flight above or below the plane of the ecliptic as more dangerous than flying planet-to-planet despite it being faster. Why is this?

OK! I got home and spent an hour flipping through pages to find the paragraph that caused my question. I thought the issue came from the attack of the pirates near the end of the book, but all I found was...

> Sadya said, "If our calculations are correct," and here Warner nodded then shrugged — 'there are no exact sciences' was one of his favorite phrases — "we'll arrive just as the battle begins out of the radiance of the sun."

Honestly, that wasn't what I thought it had said. I tried searching through the book to find a page that explained how the pirates had set themselves up, which I thought was outside the plane of the ecliptic and, therefore, unexpected. But I couldn't find that, either... so I came here to explain my problem.

Only to find that Valorum had found the explanation, one that I'd totally forgotten. It's weird that it wasn't posted as an answer... but there it is. Thanks for reminding me! And if you post it as an answer, I'll vote it and accept it.

Comment: Can you give a quote where this is described?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez My apologies, I should have done that. I'm working this morning, so I'll have it updated early this evening.

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled by the question. The passage you're referring to seems to come with its own answer to your question. "*Although it would often be faster to navigate between some planets by going above or below the solar plane, it is an unadvised practice. Coronam’s gravity well is as intense and unpredictable as its storms..."* 1/2

Comment: *"...Planer navigation – skipping between planets along the planetary ring – provides ships near shelter should a sudden storm arise or a malfunction occur. If something like that were to happen while ‘sailing the well’, as it is called, a ship might be cast into the depths of space, unable to return, or be sucked into Coronam’s fiery surface"* 2/2